# IIS Download Timeout after 2 Minutes

Tags: iis, iis-8

I have a website with an application in IIS 8.5. Now when we start a download then the connection timed out after 2 minutes.

I set the connection timeout in "Set Website Defaults" and on the application level in the web.config to 10 minutes but downloads still stop after 2 minutes.

I would be happy if someone could guide me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `<httpRuntime executionTimeout="600" />` in the web.config of your application - in the system.web section.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I suggest you could improve the connection timeout value to solve this issue.

You could open your IIS management console , click the application and find the advanced setting.

Then you could modify the connection timeout value(default is 120 seconds).

[image]

Comment: This is what I set in "Set Website Defaults" (if you select the Sites node in your connection pane then you can set the "Website Defaults" in the Actions section. It is set to 10 minutes.

Comment: Could you please tell me which web application you have used now to let the user download file? Does this application has some connect limit?